# Images Have Grey Values of True and False

Tags: python, numpy

I'm planning to process some images using PyCharm. However, I find a bug and start to find the reason. Finally, I find that the images have grey values of **True** and **False**, but they should be **1** and **0**, is there any way to change it?

The image is generated in PyCharm using:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

benign = Image.open("./benign.png")
benign = np.array(benign)

print(benign) ### Debug here!
```

[image]

The Python version is 3.8.12.

Comment: You can use `nparray.astype()` to convert it to int, use `benign.astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the np function `astype()` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)).
Use it to cast the booleans to integers:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

benign = Image.open("./benign.png")
benign = np.array(benign)
new_benign = benign.astype(int)
print(new_benign)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
benign = 1*np.array(benign)
```

this should convert True to 1 and False to 0.